# WebAPI2: Authorization code flow in micro services architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

Identity Provider: Keycloak-9.0.0
.net version: 4.5.2

Basically i am trying to integrate c# webapi service as shown in the below.

[Authorization code flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQN1v.png)

I have used the Keycloak connector( https://github.com/mattmorg55/Owin.Security.Keycloak ) for C# which is designed as an OWIN authentication middleware component

With the keycloak sample i get errors.
But i am not sure if the the call gets forwarded to keycloak for validation instead i get an error.

1. If WebAPI mode is not enabled i get "signature-validation-failed-unable-to-match-kid"
2. If webAPI mode is enabled i get 401 ({"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}Access 
   Unauthorized: Requires valid bearer token authorization header

startup class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Bearer"
            });



            app.UseKeycloakAuthentication(new KeycloakAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Realm = "test_keycloak",
                ClientId = "test",
                ClientSecret = "9f25fd55-851f-4eed-9fb9-24a0a0e4ff11",

                KeycloakUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth",
                AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Bearer",

                AllowUnsignedTokens = false,
                DisableIssuerSigningKeyValidation = false,
                DisableIssuerValidation = false,
                UseRemoteTokenValidation = true,
                EnableWebApiMode = true,
                DisableAudienceValidation = false,
                Scope= "openid",

            });
}
```

I don't see any logs in keycloak. What could be going wrong ? how do i debug?

Since its a standard Oauth2 flow, will i be able do use Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect for the token validation?

For example in java spring security has easy configurations for the same(with jwt-cert -url)

Need your inputs!

Comment: got it resolved by adding Audience mapper in keycloak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve with microsoft.owin.security.jwt as well.
Here is the code.

Note: haven't done exception handling. just basic code.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        HttpClient htpp = new HttpClient();
        var keysResponse = htpp.GetAsync("https://<FQDN of keycloak>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/certs").Result;
        
        var rawKeys = keysResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        

        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebKeySet jsonWebKeySet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebKeySet>(rawKeys);

        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
        new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            Realm = <realm>",
            
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
                
                AuthenticationType = "Bearer",
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidAudiences = new string[] { <clientID> },
                ValidIssuer = "<FQDN of keycloak>/auth/realms/<realm>",
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                IssuerSigningKeys = jsonWebKeySet.GetSigningKeys(),
                
            }
        });
    }
```